# properties in obj-c

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, properties

I've read about properties and in every tutorial it looked like this:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject{

     NSString* SomeString;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* SomeString;
```

but everything works perfectly even when line NSString* String; is missed in a class parameters.

Why it should be written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In objetive-c 2.0, the @property together with @synthesize command **will create automatically instance variables** for you (if you not have done so).
This is kind of a short cut.

When you remove `NSString* SomeString;` from your "class parameters" (iVars) your application behavior won't change because the compiler will automatically add the instance variable to your header file.

Update 1: thanks to info of Jenox, i corrected my answer.

Comment: wOOt, something wrong got accepted :O `@sythesize` creates the ivar, not `@property`

Comment: `@synthesize prop = ivar;` creates the ivar `ivar`, and `@synthesize prop;` equals `@synthesize prop = prop;`

Comment: Okay, that's a pretty cool thing. i didn't knew that too. thanks :-)